# how to fix bot from not connecting to my discord server

Tags: c#

so recently i have started coding my own bot for my teams discord server and its not connecting i followed a couple of tutorials and they didn't help me at all so here's my code.
IF anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated and thank you so much!!

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dlzbot
{
class MyBot
{
    DiscordClient discord;

    public MyBot()
    {
        discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
        {
            x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
            x.LogHandler = Log;
        });

        discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
        {
            await    discord.Connect("My Bot Token");
        });
    }

    private void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

Look at the Error!
hope this screenshot of the errors help! thanks guys
[image: ERROS HOPE THIS HELPS]

Comment: Where does the problem occur, does it stop at await discord.connect ?

Comment: Just Edited it so you can see the error for yourself thanks

Comment: Well, ehhm, may be 'no overload for method Connect takes 1 argument' ? :-)

Comment: i asked this question cause i didn't know how to solve it so please anyone thanks

Comment: Show code for DiscordClient class

Comment: Read the documentation or read the IntelliSense popup and provide the correct number of arguments. Not sure why this question got two upvotes.

Comment: what documentations?

Comment: The documentation of the library you're using.

Comment: okay i will check it out but just to let you guys know that i used this tuturial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oE6alzUzcw4  and i think everything is 100% the same

Comment: i cant find the documentation

Comment: Is this the video you were watching? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oE6alzUzcw4 Also, try await discord.Connect("token", TokenType.Bot);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using C#.

Try

```
        discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
        {
            await discord.Connect("TokenCode", TokenType.Bot);
        });
    }
```